# From your mind or By your mind, correct preposition

Tags: prepositions, british-english

I`m new to this site.

Could you please let me know the correct way of using it in English ?

Think **from** your mind and work ?

OR

Think **by** your mind and work ?

Comment: I have a problem figuring out what either of those sentences mean. Thinking is something that requires the use of one's brain (or mind) but I don't think I ever thought of thinking happening the way you describe it. You can think _with_ your mind...

Comment: I guess OP might want the idiom "Use your head" (i.e. think)

Comment: It would help us give you a better answer if we understood what you were trying to express. Usually it would be "**think with**", similar to how you see with your eyes, taste with your tongue, or think with your brain, or as others have commented **use** your eyes, tongue or brain.

Comment: As @TRomano says, "Think *using* your mind.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like thoughts can come "from your mind" but thinking itself is not usually expressed as "from your mind" - this is already part of the meaning of *think*.

You can say "Work from your mind" meaning work from what you remember, or work without an informational reference.  *Work by your mind* would likely be understood as meaning similar, but I think "X from your mind" is far more common.